# Older versions of JRE for MacOS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm trying to run an Eclipse plugin, named ESC/Java2. But turns out the plug-in is only compatible with Java Runtime Environment up to 1.5. I have a MacOS X 10.9, where the only JREs installed are 1.6 and 1.7.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about the plugin makes it incompatible with newer java? Normally there is a minimum but not a maximum.  Everthing should be backward compatible.

Comment: I'm not really sure. If I use JRE 1.6 I get *less* errors than if I use JRE 1.7. But I don't know what happens. Exact error: 
`Fatal error: A type error has occurred at an unexpected point; unable to continue processing
MARKER null 0 Fatal error: A type error has occurred at an unexpected point; unable to continue processing`

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the JVM version? A quick search suggests it is [designed for jvm 1.4 *source code*](http://www.kindsoftware.com/products/opensource/ESCJava2/) (which is obviously pretty old). Did you try setting your source code level set to 1.4?

Comment: Well, if I do that then 15+ errors show. I need to have JRE 1.5 (or 1.4) because apparently somethings changed in the compiler about transient modifiers.